# Using a shortcut key to open any resource in Visual Studio 2008

Tags: visual-studio-2008

I am learning .Net after many years of Java programming.  In Eclipse we have Ctrl Shift R to open any resource in the project.  Is there a similar keystroke in Visual Studio 2008 or is the best to use the Find in Files?

Answer (score 4):

There appears to be [an article](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/programming/mimic-the-eclipse-open-resource-feature-in-visual-studio/) describing how to mimic that functionality in VS.

Comment: Thanks for the article looks promising.

Comment: This seems like an answer to me.

Answer (score 2):

I've been using a VS add-in called [QuickOpen](http://kutny.net/vsopen/) for 6 months and it's been invaluable (on VS2008). It'll do wildcard searches, too, so you can find not only your ASPX files but also the code behind and associated resource files. Super handy.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, I'm not sure exactly what you're trying to do, since I don't use Eclipse, but what's been described looks like <kbd>ctrl-D</kbd>(Edit.GotoFindCombo) followed by

`> of myfilename`

`of` is the shortcut for `openfile`.
Note that <kbd>ctrl-D</kbd>+<kbd>></kbd> can be used for any visual studio command, including macros.

Answer (score 1):

Ctrl+, should work to navigate or search across open resources in Visual Studio.

Answer (score 0):

Ctrl+F... like anything else on your PC :)

**EDIT** You can also use the Solution Explorer and just pin it to the side of your screen: Ctrl + Alt + L

Answer (score 0):

An easier solution if your prepared to pay a small sum of money is to use [ReSharper](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/). It is based on IntelliJ IDEA and has all the same features you would expect from Eclipse (navigation, refactoring etc), but with slightly different key mappings.

If you use the IntelliJ IDEA key mappings you can achieve what you are looking for using this shortcut.

Ctrl + Shift + N