# Visual studio autocomplete to find a file?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

In the Visual Studio, do we have a tool to find a file based on file name insdie a project, like typing a few letters of beginging of a file, it will autocomplete to show all files starting with that letters. In the Java Eclipse, we can use Ctrl+Shift+R , do we have similar in the VS ?

Thanks

Comment: The Resharper plugin has a `Go To File` function (http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/features/navigation_search.html#Go_to_File)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Ctrl Shift R in Visual Studio 2008](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1209145/ctrl-shift-r-in-visual-studio-2008)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, there is something like that.

You can use the **Find** text box you use for normal searches as input for the **Command Window**. Then in the **Command Window** you have the `of` command to search files.

To do it:

- <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>/</kbd>to select the Find text box.
- Type `> of` then the file name (or part of) you want to search for.

A dropdown list will show all files that match your typing (so you do not have to know the full file name as with <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>).

If file list is pretty long you may use the normal **Find in Files** dialog, simply set **Use** to **Wildcards**, in **Find what** type * and write the search pattern in **Look at these file types**. Check the **Display file name only** option. Using the **Look in** field you can limit the search to current project, entire solution or whatever you need.

Answer (score 0):

Try ctrl-spacebar, it's the normal shortcut for intelisense. If it doesn't work for file path and name, there is surely a plugin out there just for this.

I use VS with only resharper as a plugin and I can do this, I don't know if its resharper that does it or if its prebuilt.

EDIT: It is resharper that does it. I would recommend using it if you intent to work with VS as it greatly helps out on a lot of refactoring and shortcuts.

Comment: I like those vote down with no comment -_- If you want me to improve my answer, at least leave a comment or something.

Comment: I Love Resharper, not for the Refactoring, but for it's Code Quality checks...
Coding Conventions, code corrections...

Comment: @TomerW Yes indeed. And I also like that it is fully customizable, so you can turn off suggestion that you don't like or don't need

Comment: Download "StackOverflow Downvoter address getter", and club his knees :), 
kidding, it is only -2 rep... dont feel bad

and i think the downvote was for your post has no evidence, it is a "Maybe" answer.

Comment: @TomerW I don't really care about the reputation, I just like to be able to improve myself. I guess you are right though, it must be because it was a "maybe" answer. My edit kind of clear that out however.